# File Polling using Pattern match in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Using `Azure Logic apps`, I have a requirement to poll a network file system folder for 3 files and my processing logic should start after receiving all 3 files in the file system.

I tried recurrence with `List files in folder` action and checking filenames one by one in a loop, but not working properly.

Is there a file poller trigger that checks a folder for file pattern match(`Ex: abc*.csv, ghi*.csv`) in Logic Apps?

Suggest how to implement this scenario.

Thanks,

Sunil

Comment: Any update on this issue? Could you filter it now or did you still have other problem?

Answer (score 0):

I test with the inline code with a test RegExp `/^test.*.txt$/g`, this check if the file start with test and end with .txt. The below is my code and I test with blob action.

```
var text = workflowContext.actions.Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path.outputs.body.DisplayName
var regexpattern=new RegExp(/^test.*.txt$/g);
return regexpattern.exec(text)[0]
```

[image]

If your file name match the regexp it will return the filename.

[image]